# Get key value from display value from choices in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model field with choices

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'A'),
    (1, 'B'),
    (2, 'C'),
)
```

I'm inserting rows in my database table where the category values could be A, B, or C.

Instead of using

```
if category:
    if category == "A":
        category = 0
    elif category == "B":
        category = 1
    elif category == "C":
        category = 2
```

before inserting my rows, can I somehow use my `CATEGORY_CHOICES` to translate display values to key values?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? Where does the `category` come from?

Comment: From an Excel import

Answer (score 8):

Build a dict of the `display_value: value` pairs and get the value from it:

```
CATEGORIES_D = {v: k for k, v in CATEGORY_CHOICES}
category = CATEGORIES_D[category]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
choices_dict = {}
for choice, value in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
    choices_dict[value] = choice

category = choices_dict[category]
```